# NUMA aware Cpp Container

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, parallel-processing, numa

Is there a convenient and efficient way to use the cpp standard container API in a NUMA aware fashion?

I would like to do an OpenMP parallel sparse Matrix Vector multiplication in a cpp environment.
To allocate and initialize the vector and matrix values with regards to the NUMA domains, the C code would somehow look like this:

```
size_t N = 1000000;
double* vecVal = malloc (N*sizeof(double));

#pragma OMP parallel for
for (size_i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    vecVal[i] = 0.;
}
/* do spMV */
delete vecVal;
```

In Cpp I would like to use std::vector (std::array with a fixed size is also ok).
Does std::vector::reserve() do the trick?
Is it legal to do something like this:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
vec.reserve(N);
double *vecVal = vec.data();

#pragma OMP parallel for
for (size_i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    vecVal[i] = 0.;
}
/* do spMV */
```

How can I afterwards set the correct size to the std::vector?

Does anyone knows a more elegant way?

Comment: resize() is not NUMA aware as is it initializes all values on one NUMA domain (first touch)

Comment: Is it a special thing for NUMA aware code to `delete` a `malloc`ed memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a special numa aware allocator here. We implemented something like this for HPX here: https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx/blob/master/hpx/parallel/util/numa_allocator.hpp

The basic idea is to have the first touch inside of the allocators allocate function. replace the HPX executor stuff with your `#omp parallel for schedule(static)` loop and you should be fine.